# С#: в письме отображаются текстом HTML-символы

Tags: html, c#, email

Столкнулся с такой интересной задачей: отправляю письмо, в теле которого содержится HTML. Когда письмо приходит, то HTML отображается текстом.

Как сделать так, чтобы HTML отображался правильно?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для реального проекта я бы советовал отправлять письмо с альтернативным представлением (чисто текст и HTML). Пользователи могут запретить HTML в письмах, что станет проблемой для вашей рассылки. В случае с альтернативным представлением ваша информация(пусть и не в таком красивом виде) будет доставлена. По дефолту пользователю будет отображена HTML версия письма. Пример:

```
var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            SubjectEncoding = encoding,
            Subject = subject,
            Body = textBody,
            BodyEncoding = encoding,
            IsBodyHtml = true
        };
message.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, "text/html"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Нужно установить свойство IsBodyHtml в true:

```
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{                       
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = true // это
})
```